# Connect NodeJS lambda Function to Neptune database

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have Zipped and attached Gremlin pacakage as a layer to Nodejs lambda function.

The code looks like this

```js
import gremlin from 'gremlin';
const { DriverRemoteConnection } = gremlin.driver;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;

var clusterEndpoint = process.env.NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT;  
var port = process.env.NEPTUNE_PORT; 

var connectionStrArray = [];
connectionStrArray.push("wss://");
connectionStrArray.push(clusterEndpoint);
connectionStrArray.push(":");
connectionStrArray.push(port.toString());
connectionStrArray.push("/gremlin");


const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(process.env.GRAPH_URL, {});


export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log("CONNECTING TO NEPTUNE DB");
  const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(connectionStrArray.join(""));
  console.log("Connection details:", dc);
  const graph = new Graph();
  const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);
  g.V().toList().then(data => {
    console.log("DATA:", data);
    dc.close();
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log('ERROR', error);
      dc.close();
  });
  
   const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('CONNECTION TO NEPTUNE DB SUCCESSFUL!'),
     };

  return response;
};
```

I am trying to print the connection deatils. It does print connection deatils: `console.log("Connection details:", dc);`

I am also printing query data, which is not returing any value. `console.log("DATA:", data);`

**I just need to connect to neptune database and confirm the connection. The netpune database is empty as of now.**

Comment: If it is an empty database, then the `data` value will be empty.  Are you seeing the response as `Data: []` ?  Or are you getting an `ERROR` response?